# Use Plotly to show multiple lines by value of another column in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly-python

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
fruit   number date
apple   7      2013-11-4
banana  8      2016-4-6
apple   2      2018-7-22
banana  103    2020-4-4
```

I want a line plot with two lines: the number of apples and the number of bananas as a function of the date. Is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to filter the dataframe by the value of the "fruit" column? I'd ideally like this to be able to adapt to the situation where the values and number of different values in the fruit column is not known in when the program is written.

Comment: If you want to visualize it plotly, you can use the following code. `import plotly.express as px;px.line(df, x='date',y='number', color='fruit')`

Comment: @r-beginners: Write that up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I hope my comments are helpful enough for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'fruit': ['apple', 'banana', 'apple', 'banana'],
    'number': [7, 8, 2, 103],
    'date': ['2013-11-4', '2016-4-6', '2018-7-22', '2020-4-4']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

sns.lineplot(
    x='date',
    y='number',
    hue='fruit',
    palette={'banana': 'orange', 'apple': 'green'},
    markers=True,
    data=df
)

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Number')
plt.title('Number of fruit over time')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: palette is optional

Answer (score 2):

You can filter by the fruit columns even if you don't know which fruits you have by using the .unique() method. You extract the unique fruits and then generate a line for each different fruit.
Example:

```
unique_fruits = data["fruit"].unique()
for fruit in unique_fruits:
    index = data["fruit"] == fruit # filter the columns with this particular fruit
    plt.plot(data["date"][index], data["number"][index]) # plot the numbers associated with the fruit as a function of date
plt.legend(unique_fruits)
plt.show()
```

The code will generate a graph like this, assuming you have a way to order the dates in the x axis.
[image: Graph of the data]